# FFTW producing different results from numpy.fft

Tags: python, c++, numpy, fft, fftw

I am porting some C++ code to Python. The C++ code performs the DFT and IDFT using the FFTW library, whereas in Python, I've opted to use numpys implementation for the time being.

I have come across some strange behaviour. It seems that the forward transform is computed identically in both cases, but the inverse transform produces different results!

the relevant C++ code:

```
int N = 12;
auto fft_coefficients = new complex<double>[N] {
        5.45, -0.54, 1.81, 1.49, 0.48, 3.98, 0.93, 3.98, 0.48, 1.49, 1.81, -0.54 };
fftw_plan plan_ifft = fftw_plan_dft_1d(
        N, reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(fft_coefficients),
        reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(fft_coefficients), FFTW_BACKWARD,
        FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(plan_ifft);
// Results in
// [20.82, -1.98, 4.55, 1.86, 3.63, 13.68, 1.10, 13.68,, 3.63, 1.86, 4.55, -1.98]
```

However, when I run the same code in Python, but using numpy, I get the following:

```
np.fft.ifft(np.array([5.45, -0.54, 1.81, 1.49, 0.48, 3.98, 0.93, 3.98, 0.48, 1.49,
                      1.81, -0.54], dtype=np.complex64)).real
# array([ 1.73, -0.16,  0.38,  0.15,  0.3 ,  1.14,  0.09,  1.14,  0.3 ,
#         0.15,  0.38, -0.16])
```

I thought I may need to add the `norm='ortho'` option to numpy to do unitary IDFT, but that doesn't make them match up either.

I don't understand how these two libraries could be computing the inverse DFT differently, and not just by a little bit, drastically different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FFTW claims](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html#Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs): "FFTW computes an unnormalized DFT"

That is, for ifft [they compute](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029) [image]

However, as stated on for instance [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), the inverse DFT is defined as [image]

So the fftw output is in fact incorrect and needs to be scaled.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard for normalization at least in the electrical engineering community.  None of these is "wrong", you just need to know what each library is computing and deal with it.

Comment: There is no standard normalization anywhere. Each field defines the normalization in the DFT differently. Knowing how your library normalizes is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I've found the answer. Apparently, FFTW handles normalization differently from numpy by a normalization factor. If I multiply numpys `ifft` by `N`, I get the same result as with FFTW.

This opens up another question: which one of them is skipping the normalization in the forward transform? And why? This seems like very inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: It is not inconsistent, the normalization applied in each library is the same every time. Look at the documentation to learn how each tool works. There is no single definition of the DFT. See the last paragraph of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Motivation).